# Имитация браузера через curl

Tags: php, парсер, curl, бот

Дайте подсказку. Делаю парсер. Для парсинга мне необходимо авторизоваться на сайте. Но сайт палит, что отправка логина и пароля не с браузера. Вот как выглядит `curl` :

```
    $this->ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36");
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'user_cookie_file.txt');
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'user_cookie_file.txt');
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, PAGEAUTHORIZATION);
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->postData);
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, PAGEAUTHORIZATION);
    $error = curl_exec($this->ch);
```

Параметры в пост запросе отправляю все что нужно. Авторизация иногда проходит, пример 1 раз из 20 попыток. В остальных случаях в отчет получаю страницу сайта с предупреждением о подозрительной активности. Прошу дать совет.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй посмотреть заголовки, которые ты отправляешь когда авторизовываешься, используя браузер, а затем эти заголовки подставить в свой запрос через curl

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

Тут от конкретного сайта зависит, кто что придумывает, чтобы обезопасить себя и данные

Comment: Это сработало, но не надолго. Там есть заголовок, который отправляет браузер "Cookie:" там данных капец сколько. Походу по ним как то сайт понимает спустя время что я робот. Не подскажите по каким именно критериям он может понимать? Список кук там просто безразмерный и 80% нечитаемы.

Comment: Для кук используется CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR и они уже есть. Можно попробовать еще такой вариант - не сразу отправлять этот запрос curl а перед ним отправить просто GET запрос на страницу авторизации, т.е. симулировать действия пользователя "Заход на страницу" -> "Отправка формы"

Иногда разработчики делают так, что при входе на страницу авторизации, сразу навешивают куки, которые нужно потом использоваться при отправке POST данных

Comment: В одной сессии curl/_init или в разных?

Comment: Попробуйте в разных

Comment: Все перепробовал. Сейчас даже в .NET пробую, такой же результат. Работает только если я в cookie, перед пост запросом, запихну куки которые отправляет браузер, там безобразно длинные они, именно в запросе, тогда пашет. Хз как их подменить....